# How to create GET request including table name using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express

I have this code in routes/apiRoutes.js that gets employees from the database but I need to include the table name with it.

```js
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

const db = require("../models");

//get all

router.get("/all", (req, res) => {
  db.employee.findAll().then((employees) => res.send(employees));
});

//post new

router.post("/new", (req, res) => {
  db.employee
    .create({
      text: req.body.text,
    })
    .then((submitedemployee) => res.send(submitedemployee));
});

module.exports = router;
```

I did try to use MYSQL syntax but it doesn't work

```js
var seq  = new Sequelize('mysql://localhost/mysql');
seq.query('show tables').then(function(rows) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
});
```

Comment: What you're trying to achieve , getting the list of all tables and output that as REST API??

Comment: add a catch block here to seen any errors `seq.query('show tables').then(function(rows) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
}).catch(err=>console.log(err))`

Comment: I'm trying to get data from the tables including table name when I call the API and output it in localhost(Chrome).

Comment: Can I edit this line to get the table names with the findAll() function? `router.get("/all", (req, res) => {
  db.employee.findAll().then((employees) => res.send(employees));
});` @shellakkshellu

Comment: You would like to pass the table name as argument ??

Comment: I want to have the table name included when i enter the get request @shellakkshellu